# Ceph rbd commands are hanging forever when executed on remote server

Tags: ceph, openstack-nova

I have an openstack compute node connected to ceph cluster with 10G. The compute can ping and reach the all ceph nodes and port 3300 but somehow rbd commands are hanging which is stopping the compute from creating instances in openstack. Ceph configuration file is copied on the compute as well as the relevant keyring. That same keyring is working on the controller but not on the compute.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: While the MONs require ports 3300 and 6789 to be reachable, the compute nodes also require the 6800-7300 port range to be able to connect to OSDs. Check out the [network config reference](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rados/configuration/network-config-ref/) for more details. If you do have those ports open, please provide more details. Is the ceph cluster healthy? Please add the clients and their auth caps you're using. It could be a DNS issue if you reference your hosts by name instead of IP.